# How to add shipping cost to Paypal in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, paypal

I have an order controller that will fire the following method when saved, but I am having problem to pass in shipping cost.

```
 def paypal_url(return_url,cancel_url)
    values = {
      :business => 'seller@mail.com',
      :cmd => '_cart',
      :upload => 1,
      :return => return_url,
      :invoice => @cart.id,
      :cancel_return => cancel_url,
    }
    @cart.line_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
      values.merge!({
        "amount_#{index+1}" => item.total_price,
        "item_name_#{index+1}" => item.product.title,
        "item_id_#{index+1}" => item.id,
        "quantity_#{index+1}" => item.quantity,
      })
    end
    "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
  end
```

I want to add the "Shipping and handling:" in the payment page, but I cant find the key to tell Paypal which is my shipping cost value.

[Preview image](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pps/designerfotos-addtocart-review-page.gif)

I've tried active merchant, but that is more complicated to work on.

Answer (score 0):

The Shipping and handling cost are set inside Postage calculations/Shipping Calculations in Paypal Account